# Retain select value in select box

Tags: posts, select

How are you all.
I am just struggling to make my custom select box keep retain select value in form when page is reload or user come on form via different navigation.

my select box is:

```
<?php
      $args = array('post_type'=> 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' =>100, 'offset'=> 0);
      $myposts = get_posts( $args );
      foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
      <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
      <?php endforeach;
```

in Core Php I know how to do this but in wordpress I am displaying post name in selectbox, so how can i achieve this, help would be appreciated....Thanks

Comment: You could use the_ID() as option value and get_queried_object_id() to look up in which post you are.

Comment: I am just beginner in wordpress, and love the way you provide info

Comment: Did you try the code I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you could use [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) and compare the value with [get_queried_object_id()](http://wpseek.com/get_queried_object_id/) to archive this:

```
$args       = array( 'post_type'=> 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' =>100, 'offset'=> 0 );
$myposts    = get_posts( $args );
$current_id = get_queried_object_id();
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    printf(
        '<option%s>%s</option>',
        ( $current_id == get_the_ID() ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '',
        get_the_title()
    );
}
```

---